Applying style variable with TailwindCSS in Svelte 5
I am having confusion while applying style variable with TailwindCSS in Svelte 5.
This works:
<script lang="ts">
    interface Props {
        rows: number;
        columns: number;
        size?: number;
        padding?: number;
        gridData: Cell[][];
    }

    type Cell = string;

    let { rows, columns, size = 200, padding = 8, gridData }: Props = $props();

    let calculatedCellSize = (size - 2 * padding) / Math.max(rows, columns);
    let maxCellSize = 40;
    let cellSize = Math.min(calculatedCellSize, maxCellSize);
</script>

<div
    class="w-[{size}px] h-[{size}px] box-border p-[{padding}px] flex flex-col items-center justify-center"
>
    {#each gridData as row}
        <div class="flex">
            {#each row as cell}
                <button
                    class="outline outline-1 outline-black"
                    style={`width: ${cellSize}px; height: ${cellSize}px`}
                    aria-label="arc_cell_button_{cell}"
                ></button>
            {/each}
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>

But before I tried and be successful with above working one, I failed with this one:
<script lang="ts">
    interface Props {
        rows: number;
        columns: number;
        size?: number;
        padding?: number;
        gridData: Cell[][];
    }

    type Cell = string;

    let { rows, columns, size = 200, padding = 8, gridData }: Props = $props();

    let calculatedCellSize = (size - 2 * padding) / Math.max(rows, columns);
    let maxCellSize = 40;
    let cellSize = Math.min(calculatedCellSize, maxCellSize);
</script>

<div
    class="w-[{size}px] h-[{size}px] box-border p-[{padding}px] flex flex-col items-center justify-center"
>  <!-- This element worked well!!! -->
    {#each gridData as row}
        <div class="flex">
            {#each row as cell}
                <button
                    class="w-[{cellSize}px] h-[{cellSize}px] outline outline-1 outline-black"
                    aria-label="arc_cell_button_{cell}"
                ></button> <!-- But this one did not -->
            {/each}
        </div>
    {/each}
    </div>

However the most confusing point is: the root container of the component's style is well applied. In the web inspector, actually the class variable seem to be working well (e.g. class="w-[18px]" )
